# how to generate a stream of raw data?

Tags: c++, algorithm, 64-bit, stream

Tools:

- OS: Win XP,
- MSVC++

The problem is that I want to generate some "**raw data**" stream, by that I mean a stream of random 1s and 0s, next I want to send this genrated stream over udp sockets.

any ideas on how to generate that stream?

I hope I was clear in my question and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using UDP, you're not really going to get a "stream", because UDP is not a stream-oriented protocol like TCP. You can generate lots of random UDP packets, however. Just generate random integers with rand() or whatever and send them over UDP.

Comment: what do you mean by random integers? is it random 1s & 0s or smth else?otherwise, do you know where can I find some raw data files on the net in order to use it as source ?

Comment: What do you mean by "raw data"? Since all data in our computers is represented in binary form a random number will be nothing more than a collection of random 1's and 0's. You might even just send the contents of some arbitrary file through UDP and that would pretty much satisfy your requirements.